# Strange Twig behaviour when using "in" operator

Tags: twig

Today I noticed strange behaviour then trying to check if array has value.

I tried to do `{% if key in array|keys %} ... {% endif %}`
and condition was equal to `true` always.

I tried to do this later: `{{ dump('a' in [0, 1, 2]) }}`.

And guess what value was dumped? It was "true" somehow.
Do you guys have any idea why is it happening?

I can workaround it by using `'a' in [0, 1, 2]|join` but that's not what I want to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not twig, it's php. The following code:

```
var_dump(in_array('a', array(0, 1, 2)));
```

prints:

```
bool(true)
```

When comparing a string to an int, the string gets converted to int. In this case, 'a' becomes 0, thus matching one of the array keys.

Try doing a `var_dump("foobar" == 0)` and you'll see it is true as well.

You can use `foo['a'] is defined` instead, demo here: http://twigfiddle.com/y126mg